# Is there any api to filter all table columns by some value?

Tags: java, spring-data

I need to search given columns in some database table by given value.

I can do it simply by something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE "%value%" OR col2 LIKE "%value%"
```

But maybe there is another way with spring-data or other API where I can pass value, and columns(maybe annotating them) to search by as parameters and it does filtering for me?

Comment: What database are you using? In case of mysql you can query information_schema.

Comment: I am using Postgres.

Comment: No such filter in JPA nor Spring Data, because such filter is not ORM-oriented. The only way is to use dialect-specific `@Query`-annotated method

Comment: You can query: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table